# Does the below sentence imply a relative or an immediate family member?

Tags: grammar

No, I can't abandon her, she's family.

Comment: Two things please.  1) more context.  Who is speaking, to whom? What was the surrounding text?   **and** 2) The source.  If you wrote this yourself, please say say so, and say the context in which you want to use this.

Comment: In context both the speaker and the listener would know the identity of "her" so there is no   question if she is a distant relative or immediate family member.

Comment: Yes. This sentence does imply that "she" is a relative or an immediate family member.

Answer (score 1):

It may possibly mean "immediate family," daughter, sister, wife, mother, grandmother, but that is not likely because the specific relationship would usually be made explicit.

Probably, it means "extended family." Without further clues, the extended family is not precisely defined in modern American English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a relative. Not necessarily immediate family. She could be a niece, cousin, aunt, etc.